How can we customized the Strapi Admin User Profiles like adding more fields to it other than name email passwords
In Strapi how to Customize the Admin User Profile here: 

Is it possible to do so by making a change in Strapi code?
I am expecting mode fields there in User Profile other than first name,last name,email and password. I want my custom fields like departments,colleges, etc.
